# SQL Server Insert Failed (Not preventing rest of script)

Tags: sql-server

This is probably a simple question but im doing some inserts for a company, and some of the inserts "might" already exist. So it will fail since primary key value is already there etc...

The question is.....will the rest of the updates/inserts go through? or will the whole thing fail?

Is there a way to just overwrite it anyways or continue on with the rest of the script if not?

Thanks

Comment: This can depend on a lot of factors about how you're doing the inserts.  Have you tested this to find out the behavior?  If you're trying to insert duplicate identifiers then that's probably an indication that something else is wrong with the overall design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a set based operation:

```
INSERT <foo>
SELECT <stuff>
```

Then the operations is atomic -- either all of it will work, or none of it will (And this is a GOOD THING). However if you are doing a cursor based single item insert then the insert failures will probably not abort the batch. However, this is horribly slow.

What you really want though is to use MERGE statement -- assuming that you are using sql server 2008 or better.

Or you can add a WHERE NOT EXISTS () clause to your INSERT Statement to make sure you don't try to insert rows that allready exist.

Read here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Well they are actually all inserts (then a group of updates). Problem is these are like LARGE sections of inserts. And basically I do not know if some records exist or don't. I might have to split them up just to ease the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TRY/CATCH block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) or verify if a row already exists before using INSERT.